# Accessing JSON data in elisp

Tags: json, hash-tables

JSON:

```
{
  "name": "xxxxx",
  "job": "xxxxxx",
  "projects": [
    {
      "name": "xxxxx",
      "date": "xxxxx",
      "about": "xxxxxxxxxx"
    },
    {
      "name": "xxxxx",
      "date": "xxxxx",
      "about": "xxxxxxxxxx"
    },
    {
      "name": "xxxxx",
      "date": "xxxxx",
      "about": "xxxxxxxxxx"
    }
  ]
}
```

Elisp file:

```
(let ((json-object-type 'hash-table)
      (json-array-type 'list)
      (json-key-type 'string))
  (setq data (with-temp-buffer
               (insert-file-contents (elt argv 0))
               (buffer-string))))
```

How to access the first element in projects list (json array)?

Note:
According to https://github.com/thorstadt/json.el/blob/master/json.el (read-json) should be used instead of setq but it doesn't show a clear example on how to do that. Also I have chosen hash-tables as the json-object-type as in comparision of plist and alist it seems favorable to me.

Comment: Only one question per question, please.

Comment: @Drew burden my curiosity, I thought it is such a common operation, that a good answer would suffice for all the questions included.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've taken the liberty of adjusting your code appropriately:

```
(require 'json)

(let* ((json-object-type 'hash-table)
       (json-array-type 'list)
       (json-key-type 'string)
       (json (json-read-file "test.json")))
  (car (gethash "projects" json)))
```

The `let*` is required because otherwise the call to `json-read-file` will not see the previously bound values as `let` sets them in parallel...

As for the access functions, `gethash` retrieves a value by key from a hash table, whereas `car` returns the first list element.  If you need a different one, you can use `nth` with an index.

To actually iterate over the projects:

```
(require 'json)

(let* ((json-object-type 'hash-table)
       (json-array-type 'list)
       (json-key-type 'string)
       (json (json-read-file "test.json"))
       (projects (gethash "projects" json)))
  (dolist (project projects)
    ...))
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. 

how can i get access to the resulting list from (car (gethash "projects" json))) to use it in a dolist(project projects) ?

Comment: This does not result into a list, but a hash table.  Assuming you actually want to iterate over all projects, don't access the first list item in the first place.